# Apache Security Patch update in centos version 5.4

Tags: apache-2.2, centos5, patch-management

I am running centos version 5.4 with apache version 2.2.3, I want to get latest security patches for this apache version.

I checked the last update for apache via

`rpm -q --changelog httpd | less`

and it shows

`Thu Mar 25 2010 Karanbir Singh <kbsingh@centos.org> 2.2.3-31.el5.centos.4`
`- Roll in CentOS Branding`

`Thu Mar 04 2010 Joe Orton <jorton@redhat.com> - 2.2.3-31.4`
`- require and BR a version of OpenSSL with the secure reneg API (#567980)`
`.......`

Now when I run `yum update httpd` , it says

`No Packages marked for Update`.

So is there any way I can update to the latest patch from centos? also I do not want to update from third party repositories.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're actually running CentOS 5.4, you may want to consider updating to 5.8.  The `httpd` package, for example, has updates as recent as early 2012.

If `yum update` is not updating anything, it's because the repository you're pointing at does not have anything more recent. This suggests that you're local yum configuration points explicitly at *CentOS 5.4* rather than more generically to *CentOS 5*.  Take a look at your `yum` configuration in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`; it should look something like this:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5

# ...and a few more entries...
```

If your `mirrorlist` entries look different, or if you're pointing at an explicit URL using `baseurl` instead of `mirrorlist`, try updating the entries to look like this and running `yum update` again.

This file (`/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`) is installed by the `centos-release` package, so you could also consider grabbing the package [from a mirror](http://mirror.stanford.edu/yum/pub/centos/5/os/i386/CentOS/centos-release-5-8.el5.centos.i386.rpm) and installing it manually, then running `yum update`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, thats is very helpfull answer, I just checked and in my server there are explicit baseurl, I will just change and check and will update you, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The latest version from the CentOS 5.x branch is 5.8. Your install is quite old.

Could you try *yum check-update* ? If not try, *yum clean all* and try again.